# Efficient way of shifting row down in ASP table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've dynamically created an ASP table in the program:

```
 <asp:Table ID="tblTimesheet" runat="server" style="width: 100%;"> 
  <asp:TableHeaderRow> ....  </asp:TableHeaderRow> 
  ... </asp"Table>
```

with rows generated using such function:

```
protected TableRow GenerateRow(int rownum)
{
TableRow row = new TableRow();
TextBox tbWorked= new TextBox();
tbWorked.ID= "tbWorked+.rownum.ToString();
Label lblDay = new Label();
lblDay.ID= "lblDay"+rownnum.ToString();
...
TableCell Cell0 = new TableCell();
Cell0.Controls.Add(tbWorked);
TableCell Cell1 = new TableCell();
Cell1.Controls.Add (lblDay);
...
row.Cells.Add(Cell0);
row.Cells.Add(Cell1);
...
return row
};
```

As you can see each row has lots of different types of controls each named as `controlname+rowNumber.ToString();` So label `lblDay` in 6th row will be `lblDay6` (yes, I know rows are indexed from 0 but there is header row that I've omitted). Now each row has also a button, which I'd like if it could:

1. Generate new row (which is easy, since I can use this function above and the `rownum` parameter can be taken from the button's ID)
2. Shift all rows down, so the nth-row will become n+1 and new row will be just below the row containing the pressed button.

How to efficiently shift the row? You can't do

```
`tblTimesheet.Rows[n] = blTimesheet.Rows[n-1]
```

Obvious solution would be going through controls by names

```
private void ReindexTable (int rowNum)
{
 int maxrows = tblTimesheet.Rows.Count;
 TableRow newRow = GenerateRow(maxrows+1);
 tblTimesheet.Rows.Add(newRow);
 for (int x= maxrows+1; x>rowNum; x--)
 {
     Label lblDaySource = tblTimesheet.FindControl("lblDay"+(x-1).ToString());
     label lblDayDest = tblTimesheet.FindControl("lblDay" +x.ToString());
     lblDayDest.Text = lblDaySource.Text
   ....
```

etc for all other control types, but this approach seems very... inelegant.

Is there a better way?

EDIT: @Eric Philips answer pointed me into right direction

```
private void ReindexTable (int rowNum)
{
 int maxrows = tblTimesheet.Rows.Count;
 TableRow newRow = GenerateRow(maxrows+1);
 for (int x=maxrows; x>rowNum; x--)
 {
  TablerRow rowx = tblTimesheet.Rows[x-1];
  tblTimesheet.Rows.AddAt(x,rowx);
 }
 tblTimesheet.Rows.addAt(rownum,newRow);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.AddAt(...)` function to insert at a specific index.

```
tblTimesheet.Rows.AddAt(int index, TableRow row)
```

Just pass in the index of from your button to insert above:

```
tblTimesheet.Rows.AddAt(providedIndex, myNewTableRow)
```

Comment: Could you please add whole loop? Would it be something like `TableRow oldRow = tblTimesheet.Rows[x-1];  tblTimesheet.Rows.AddAt(x, oldRow)` ?